# using instanceof on strongly typed errors always returns false

Tags: typescript

I'm using a library that has a bunch of strongly typed errors that I would like to catch and handle in my code.  See https://github.com/ccxt/ccxt/blob/master/ccxt.d.ts#L12

The problem is, when the library throws one of these erorrs, I'm unable to figure out which error it is.  I'm currently using `instanceof`, but it always returns false.

What is the correct way in modern typescript to handle typed errors?

[edit] found this https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13965 - is it possible that it's just not a supported feature?

Comment: It's a mismatch between the declaration file and the source code

Comment: Please include your code directly in the question, not as a link.

Comment: That isn't my code.  It's a link to a the library I'm using.